# How to read ISBN from eBooks on CHM or PDF files

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, pdf, chm

I'm doing a database for storing my eBook collection.
Most of them have the ISBN within the text of the book itself.
How can I access this contents?
Is there any sourcecode or DLLs for doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it for eBook library app. First of all you need to extract text from chm or pdf file. There are a lot of utilities\libraries to do it. Here is an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/decompilingchm.aspx) on CodeProject on how to extract content from CHM files. For PDF files I used [pdftotext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext) utility.
When you get plain text from eBook parse it using [regular expression](http://regexadvice.com/blogs/dneimke/archive/2003/12/06/179.aspx) to find ISBN10/13 code.

Answer (score 3):

Extracting the text from [CHM](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/decompilingchm.aspx) and [PDF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/PDFToText.aspx) files is the first step. Next you can find the ISBN number with a [regular expression](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/viewD8902276-CCD3-4B93-8D27-A7A1908D25D3.htm).